# Can I travel to Burma/Myanmar over land across the border from China?

Tags: china, borders, overland, myanmar, land-borders

I'm currently in Kunming and there is a Myanmar consulate here.

I'm assuming most people fly. I know there has been some quite recent trouble in the area.

**But is it still possible to visit Myanmar by land from China?**

Searching the Internet turns up some pages but, as always, many are out of date and/or contain conflicting information.

- Do I need a permit?
- Do I have to be part of a tour group?

A receptionist at my hostel in Kunming tells I can enter by land but doesn't know all the details. Only that you must leave by the same means of transport by which you arrive, and across the same border.

Comment: I was under the impression that they were heavily limiting tourist visas, no?

Comment: @CMaster: I didn't get that impression. In the six months I've been in this part of the world I've met many people who had travelled there either before or after I met them. I don't think any did it overland from China though.

Comment: No, seems I was under the wrong impression.
I can see that if you get an eVisa, you must arrive by air to one of three international airports. However for a paper visa from an embassy, no restrictions on entry are mentioned...

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get into Burma over land or took plane/skipped the country altogether?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: No, as it happens I have not yet visited Burma on any of my trips.

Answer (score 2):

About the best information I can find is on a [tour operator website](http://www.go-myanmar.com/arriving-and-departing-over-land), which says:

> China crossing
>
> To cross the land border at Ruili (known as Shweli in Burmese and
>   located in China’s Yunnan Province) / Muse (Myanmar, Shan State), you
>   will need to arrange a special tour package by filling out this form;
>   the package will include a guide and mandatory private transportation.
>   You will need to apply at least one month in advance of your travel
>   date.
>
> If you are travelling from China, an alternative is to go to a travel
>   agent in Kunming. The Myanmar consulate in Kunming may tell you that
>   the border is officially shut, but this, in fact, will probably not be
>   the case.

It certainly sounds as if special permits and tour operators are needed. The eVisa available over the internet is [only valid for entry in to Yangon International Airport, Nay Pyi Taw International Aiport and Mandalay International Airport](http://evisa.moip.gov.mm/NoticetoTourists.aspx). I could find no mention of restricted entry for a visa acquired directly from an embassy however. It is noted throughout the internet that much of Mynamar is not permitted for visit by tourists, which will restrict where you can enter.

Unfortunately, sounds like our best answer to this is likely for you to try it and report back.

Comment: My experiences with following up on information of this nature in Cambodia and Vietnam has made me very sceptical indeed of how much must be done by an agent. But sometimes it even turns out that it's cheaper and quicker to go through an agent. Where are our expert travellers who have actually done this? (-:

Comment: Yes, the "special form" that you must fill in is just the booking enquiry form of the agent...

Comment: Well... Maybe... (-:

Answer (score 0):

If you travel by land, you need to apply for a visa through a Myanmar Embassy or Myanmar consulate in Kunming.
To travel with your own vehicle, you must register a tour package with an authorized travel agency in Myanmar.

Comment: Can you please post a link that proves this statement.

Comment: (Or, at least, some description of how you obtained this information; for instance, "personal experience," plus a short explanation, is absolutely ok.)